# Can't get src of img (JS, Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some table.

```
            <table>                
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><img src="uploads/0/58.gif"></td>
                <td>Name 1</td>
                <td>8</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><img src="uploads/0/25.gif"></td>
                <td>Name2</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Need to get src of all images from table. I'm doing some replaces in table, so
var tbl = $('table').html();

After replaces, I need to get src-s:
I really don't know how to write it, like $(tbl + 'tr').each....
So I write:

```
       $('table tr').each(function(index){ 
            let tds = $(this).find('td'); // get array td-s
            console.log(typeof(tds.html())) // Object
            console.log(tds[1]) // <td><img src="uploads/0/58.gif"></td>
            //$('img').src // error
            //$('img').getAttribute('src') // error,
            //$(this).find('img').src // error
            //ets...
        });
```

I try somethink like

or $(this).find('img) // == Object, i can't get src from

Comment: Within the tr loop: `var img  = $(this).find("img");  img.attr("src", new_src);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more complete selector:

```
$('table td > img[src]').each(function(i, e) { });
```

Or for all images in the page with a source, it would look like this:

```
$('img[src]').each(function(i, e) { console.log(e.src); });
```

You might want to read up on CSS selectors :)

Comment: It's good solution, but I try to understand, how to get some elements or attibutes, using "find". Because I check top-10 google "jquery find", and there only examples like $('p').find('span').addClass....

Comment: And also I get absulute way, by your solution, need relative, like: 'uploads/0/9.gif'
Now I get :C://Documents/change/Biathlon/uploads/0/9.gif

Comment: img src is always absolute - it's converted from relative in the .html file to absolute in the DOM when the browser parses/renders the html.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution based on your tried examples is:

```
console.log(tds[1].firstChild.src);
```

To get result inside a loop:

```
$('table tr').each(function(index){ 
    console.log(tds[1].firstChild.src);
});
```